# Why did I (not) receive a message saying I have been granted a privilege even though I (don't) have enough reputation?

Tags: support, faq, reputation, notifications, privileges

The site shown a message saying I have been granted a privilege, but the reputation required for that privilege is higher than the one I actually have.

The opposite case can also happen: one can receive enough reputation to earn a privilege but not have received a notification about it.

What happened in each case?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Got a message of earning a privilege, but don't have enough reputation

As stated officially [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72270/privilege-banner-buggy-or-am-i-just-confused/72283#72283), this behavior is by design.

Your reputation was indeed over the threshold briefly (thereby triggering the message), but your reputation later dropped back below the threshold. This can happen if a user retracts their vote, if one of your posts got downvoted, if a post or user was removed, or serial upvotes were reversed.

Note that once you receive a privilege notification message, you will not receive a second message for the same privilege, regardless of how many times your rep goes over the threshold again.

### Didn't get a message of earning a privilege, but have enough reputation

This is because you crossed the privilege threshold as a result of your reputation being [recalculated](/tags/reputation-recalc).

One case where this can happen is when you get serially downvoted, get some legitimate upvotes that would have pushed you over the privilege threshold had you not received the serial downvotes but didn't, then the automated scripted reversed the serial votes. As an example, suppose you have 980 reputation and never earned the established user privilege (1,000 reputation); you receive ten serial downvotes pushing you to 960 reputation, then three legitimate upvotes bringing you to 990, then the automated script reverses the serial downvotes so you now have 1,010 reputation.

Other cases of this happening are when you cross a threshold as a result of a post which had a net negative effect on your reputation (either through downvotes or putting a bounty) getting deleted, when a user who had downvoted one or more of your posts gets removed, or when you get upvoted while suspended and those upvotes are enough to push you to another privilege you didn't have before getting suspended.

One final case was during the [great reputation recalculation of late 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339048/377214) when question upvotes were revalued at 10 reputation instead of 5 reputation.

In any case, you will receive any notifications you didn't receive the next time an event other than a recalculation occurs that gives you reputation (such as an upvote, earning a bounty, or approved suggested edit).

Comment: So once you get a privilege, you can not "un-earn" it?

Comment: @alex: No, your privileges are always dependent on your current rep level (i.e., you can lose privileges). It's just the *message* that you've earned a privilege will be shown only once.