# Possible bug with privilege alert for View Close Votes

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, privileges, alerts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did I receive a message saying I have been granted a privilege, yet I don't have enough reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73673/why-did-i-receive-a-message-saying-i-have-been-granted-a-privilege-yet-i-dont-h)

I got the following alert today:

[image: Alert: earned the privilege - view close votes]

However, notice the number of points I have. Looking at the privileges page, I see I still haven't got the required points:

[image: Privileges: privilege for view close votes is only 96% earned]

Now, 240 points is 96% of the way to 250, so perhaps there has been a change to one but not the other at some point in time?  That's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required rep for view close votes is indeed 250 according to the [privileges page.](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes)  The only thing that I can think of that might have happened is that you were upvoted over 250 and then downvoted, or a user who upvoted you was deleted, or someone took back an upvote, or you lost rep another way.

An upvote is 10 points, so it would only take you gaining and then losing 1 upvote for this to happen.

Comment: I know I didn't lose the points through my own action, but I didn't realise points could be lost under those conditions too.  Looking at the reputation log, nothing appears to be out of order, but perhaps I wouldn't be able to tell anyway. Now, I have just gone over 250 points and I got the alert again, so it's most likely that you're right!

Comment: @BoffinbraiN: Rep lost through deletions is not shown in the rep log.  That information is .. deleted! `:P`