# Why did I earn vote down privilege before 125 reputation score?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did I receive a message saying I have been granted a privilege, yet I don’t have enough reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73673/why-did-i-receive-a-message-saying-i-have-been-granted-a-privilege-yet-i-dont)

I'm pretty sure, unless I'm unable to show now, that I earn the "Vote Down" privileges before reaching 125 of reputation.

Indeed, obtained it at almost 110. I was really proud of myself ( ;) ), seeing notification, and I immediatly went to privileges list. I discovered that I was near 91%, or 93% or reaching the right level.

Is it a bug ? Is it possible to reproduce it (even now I got it) ?
I didn't tried it, so maybe it is linked to [Why did I receive a message saying I have been granted a privilege, yet I don't have enough reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73673/why-did-i-receive-a-message-saying-i-have-been-granted-a-privilege-yet-i-dont), but I'm unable to verify it now.

If it's really linked, feel free to delete it (or let me do it by myself).

Comment: Most likely just a reversed upvote/accept...nothing to see here.

Comment: Do you think I had to delete my post John ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The notification is triggered when you first reach that reputation level. If your reputation drops below the privilege threshold again, the notification won't go away.

So if you earned the vote down privilege at 110 rep, you probably had an answer accepted, which put you at 125 rep, and then unaccepted again. Indeed it seems that some people do this on purpose to mess with you if they see that you're close to a new privilege. Happened to me way more often than is plausible.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't I saw variations in history ? It seems that I progressed slowly, and I didn't obtain 125 in the same time ...a few hours later maybe ! It's probably what happened, but I'm pretty sure that votes didn't moved so quick... well no matter ...

Comment: Not necessarily. If someone upvotes you or accepts an answer and then retracts it shortly after, it won't show up in your history. I think this is because you used to be able to spam someone's rep history by rapidly voting and then undoing it again.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Oh really great ! I didn't ever see this screen ! Really, really thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 8):

What probably happened was this:

1. You hit 126+ reputation.
2. The "you have gained the vote down privilege" message was sent.
3. Either a post (or posts) from you was removed or an up-vote or two was rescinded, or an acceptance was removed which took you down to less than 125 points.
4. You received the message.

The next time you get more than 125 points you wont get the message.

Comment: Thanks for your help too ! I couldn't figure out that changing opinion (or votation) could be so quick (+1)