# Return of the erroneous "you've gained the privilege" notification?

Tags: bug, notifications, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why did I earn vote down privilege before 125 reputation score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135658/why-did-i-earn-vote-down-privilege-before-125-reputation-score)

In February 2011, there was a [change to privilege system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78859/did-i-lose-the-vote-down-privilege-and-then-get-it-back) which pushed old notifications to users who didn't get them. Today I received such a notification:

> "Congrats, you've gained the privilege - vote down"
>
> [image: notification]

The thing is, my notification was not "lost in the mail". In fact, my reputation history shows that I never surpassed the required `125` reputation to gain this privilege!

[image: reputation]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0 reputation gain recorded for the day indicates that you were most likely upvoted and then the upvote got retracted. It temporarily put you over the required threshold, which triggered the notification, then you fell back below it.

Comment: Does this only happen when the new upvotes and downvotes balance out on the same post in the same day? Do the events get recorded when I get `+10` in one post and then `-10` in another on the same day?

Comment: No, it would happen when the same upvote got retracted. Likely someone upvoted your answer and then retracted that upvote within the 5-minute grace period.

Comment: Ah. I see. You'd think the privilege system would wait until after that grace period... Thanks!